# Swift Обновление TabBar

Tags: xcode, swift

Есть TabBarController, с несколькими вкладками. В одной вкладке я меняю значение в таблице, а в другой вкладке отображается уже измененное значение. Но это работает, только когда срабатывает viewDidLoad. Можно ли как то обновить вкладку нажатием на ее иконку, или же фоново постоянно данные обновлять?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Использовал функцию viewWillAppear

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
//ваши данные 
}
```